# make two css classes be the same

Tags: css, templates, struts2

This is a general question:
Is it possible to make to css classes be the same:
requiredInput = reqInp

Here is the problem:
I am using Struts 2 css_xhtml template.
It generates some predefined div with css classes. On the other hand I want to use a css frame work for managing the form style ( yaml). 
Luckily the structure of the generated div and css are same as the one which is defined in the frame work.
The only issue is that the name of the css classes which defined in css is different from the one which is generated by struts.
Is there any way which I can define
I do not want to change the source of css frame work too.

The structured of generated html is fine: 
I need to make wwlbl and wwwctrl equal too other css classes

```
<div id="wwlbl_Test" class="wwlbl">   
<label for="Test" class="label">Test
</label></div> <br>
   <div id="wwctrl_Test" class="wwctrl">
       <input name="amount" value="" id="Test" type="text">
   </div> 
</div>
```

PS: I do not want to define my own template for struts and change the css classes there.

Comment: why don't you use `simple` theme of Struts2, it will not generate any CSS or div for you and let you to do everything from your-side

Comment: As I mentioned the struts css_XHTML generates good div and css styles. I do not need to change any thing. I just need to make tell the browser that for examle the struts class (wwctrl) is same as yaml (ym_form) class

Answer (score 1):

You can always just give two different classes the same style:

```css
.requiredInput, .reqInp {
    color:#f00;
}
```

Comment: The css frame work already has lots of css files which lots of classes. If I want to use this solution I should open the css framework css files and change them. or copy all classes from css framework to new css file and change them! which I want to avoid

Answer (score 1):

First, 
Overwrite yout css for positions problems :

```
.wwgrp .wwctrl br {
 display: none;
}

.wwlbl {
 float: left;
 clear: both;
}

.wwctrl { 

}

.sradio {
 margin: 0px 6px 0;
}
```

Second, for fixing margin ,spaces, or padding in an element form example Radio|CheckBox

```
<s:radio ... cssClass="sradio"../>
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by Umesh, you can simply `use the simple theme` or you can use the `cssClass` attribute which is present in all struts2 UI tags.

`<s:textfield name="companyName" label="Company Name" cssClass="t1"></s:textfield>`

Comment: please review the question update, the cssClass does not change the generated css for divs!

Comment: you've got to use a combination of "simple" and what I suggested.